# mapping from one set of column names to another using stringdist

Tags: r, string, dataframe, mapping

I have thousands of files that I am trying to put together.  They all have various related column names, which are sometimes missing and I am trying to standardize them and put them together. Below is the code I have so far. It generates a stringdistmatrix. The question I have is how to assign only those fields that have a really good match to the columns in the reference list? Is there a better way to get where I want. This is the end result that I seek:

```
Address1               Address2                 City         State Zipcode Phone
Berewick Town Center   Beretown Town Center Dr  Charlotte    NC    99999   (704) 999-9999
Colony Place           7823 Colonial Rd         Charlotte    NC    99999   (704) 999-9999
Warwick Blvd           12404 Warwick Blvd       Newport News VA    99999   (757) 999-9999
Ballantyne Commons     15007 John J. Delano Dr  Charlotte    NC    99999   (704) 999-9999
```

Below is the code so far..

I really appreciate any suggestions, ideas! Thank you!!

```
Address1<-c("Berewick Town Center","Colony Place","Warwick Blvd","Ballantyne Commons")

Address2<-c("4821 Beretown Town Center Dr","7823 Colonial Rd","12404 Warwick Blvd","15007 John J. Delano Dr")

City<-c("Charlotte","Charlotte","Newport News","Charlotte   NC")    
  
State<-c("NC","NC","VA","NC")

PostalCode<-c(99999,99999,99999,99999)

Phone<-c("(704) 999-9999","(704) 999-9999","(757) 999-9999","(704) 999-9999")

df1<-data.frame(Address1 , Address2, City, State, PostalCode, Phone)
  
library(stringdist)
     reference<-c("AddressName","Address1","Address2","Address3","City","State","Zipcode","Country","Phone","Fax")
     y<-data.frame(matrix(ncol=length(reference), nrow=0, dimnames = list(NULL, reference)))
     temp<-stringdistmatrix(names(y),names(df1), useNames=TRUE, method='dl')
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the column names ? In your expected output the only change that I see from `df1` is that column name `PostalCode` is changed to `Zipcode`.

Comment: Hi Ronak,Yes I am changing the column names based on the similarity of df1 to the desired column names of reference..

Comment: What for do you need such an uniformization, @tom? To bind all your dataframes into a single one? Do all your dataframes have the same sequence of columns (although with names that may be different from dataframe to dataframe)?

Comment: Hi Paul, I have data coming from many different sources. They are all in excel format. Each file has 1 or many worksheets. In addition, to the nonstandard naming, the column headers for each worksheet are in a different location and not set in excel.  Many of them have different formats like for instance  Address1, Address Line 1, Address1:, Address.. They can be and are in all sorts of orders.. There is nothing uniform about them. My goal is to standardize them  and be able to rbind all of the files together. Sorry for the long winded explanation..